# Объяснение конструкции

Tags: java, return, if

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ComplexNumber that = (ComplexNumber) o;
        return Double.compare(that.re, re) == 0 &&
                Double.compare(that.im, im) == 0;
    }
```

Не могу понять конструкцию(if ... return; if ... return; ... return) представленную в коде. Каким именно образом она работает? Прочитал, что данная конструкция то же самое, что и if... else if ... else if..., однако не понимаю почему это работает, ведь если первое условие выполняется, то для чего идти дальше? Как мне представляется, при компиляции происходит обход всех условий и на основе всех условий формируется конечный возврат true/false(возможно это не так, прошу объяснить). Мое предположение, что ответ кроется в том, что на этапе компиляции происходит проверка всех условий, а не как в Питоне - построчное чтение и именно поэтому if можно писать друг за другом.

Comment: Если выполняется, то дальше ничего и не идёт. А если НЕ выполняется, то идёт.

Comment: Никто не гарантирует что условие не повторится и результат будет выдаваться не однозначно, а что не может происходить в одной точке кода.

Answer (score 1):

При вызове оператора `return` метод досрочно завершается и дальнейший код метода не исполняется

Comment: Такое быть не может, обезвтельно должен стоять условные оператор

Comment: Верно, спасибо что подправили, ведь иначе будет ошибка

Answer (score 0):

```java
if (this == o) return true;
```

Здесь если `this == 0` то функция **возвращает значение**, то есть **завершается** и дальше не выполняется

Answer (score -1):

Это конструкция работает как в Python, так и в Java.

Оператор выхода из функции `return` может работать практически в любой строчке кода. Делается это именно для того, чтобы не ходить дальше и не вычислять ничего после этого кода. Этот оператор можно даже вставлять в циклы, что часто делается:

```
for(int i : list) if(i == 10) return true;
```

Если вы знаете, что условие неверное, то зачем идти дальше? Никаких предварительных расчетов нигде не делается, разве что оптимизация, но это уже другое.

Аналог из Питона:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def equals(self, o):
        if (self == o): 
            return True
        if (o == None or self.__class__.__name__ != o.__class__.__name__): 
            return False
        return self.name == o.name
    
class NoTest:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a = Test("Вася")
b = Test("Вася")
c = Test("Петя")
d = NoTest("Петя")

print(a.equals(b))
print(a.equals(c))
print(a.equals(a))
print(a.equals(None))
print(c.equals(d))
```

Comment: В любой строчке не может. Без причины не бывает следствия.

Comment: Почему бы не добавить else if? Вить суть от этого не поменяется

Comment: @RomanC, с точки зрения синтаксиса это не важно, к тому же "практически любая != любая". @DevJ, а Вы можете ответить, почему бы не оставить и так, если уж суть от этого не меняется? Запись с `else if` будет привычнее в данном случае, согласен, но это только демонстрация. В реальном коде можно встретить сложные условия, которые надо будет задокументировать. Тогда возможно такая запись будет удобнее. Просто для того, чтобы человек не просматривал всю ветвь зависимостей. В остальном все относительно и пишут по `code style`, принятым в компании.

Comment: Синтаксис здесь ни при чем.

Comment: @RomanC, ладно, вы не поняли о чем я, но это и не важно. Я к тому, что если в какое-то место можно поставить `return`, то это именно синтаксис и неважно, имеет выражение смысл или нет. Примеры без if, синглтон в простом виде: `public static Service test() { return this.service; }` или просто бессмысленный код `public void test() { for(;;) return; }`.

Comment: Нет. Это вы меня не поняли, я вам поставил комментарий, чтобы вы обратили внимание на неверное выражение - "Оператор выхода из функции return может работать практически в любой строчке кода". Не может он работать в любой строчке кода, например если его вставить между двумя утверждениями без условного оператора.

Comment: @RomanC, я уже написал "практически любая != любая", думаю на этом можно закончить, разговор ни о чём получается). Я понял что вы хотите сказать еще с первого раза. В java действительно нельзя два return подряд, но некоторые другие языки позволяют и такое проделывать.

Comment: Не два return подряд, а все что идёт после него надо удалять иначе твой код не скомпилируется если есть код состоящий из утверждений, то ты никак туда не вставишь return между ними. В силу вышеупомянутого оператор return не может практически, и не практически, по любому работать в любой строчке кода. Он будет работать если выполнено условие выхода из метода или же является последним оператором в методе.

Comment: @RomanC, тогда потрудитесь объяснить, почему приведенный по ссылке код скомпилируется или выполнится для всех упомянутых языков без ошибок: https://pastebin.com/1dA85Q7c Хотя уже этот факт говорит о том, что где-то вы не правы практически, а не теоретически.

Comment: Тут, у вопросе, речь идёт о языке java, в котором такое недопустимо и компилятор выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @RomanC, в вопросе, речь так же идет о питоне. Да и почему вы потом проигнорировали тот факт, что я об этом сам и сказал в контексте java? Видимо, моя манера отвечать не слишком вам подходит и вы не поняли моего ответа. Могу только сказать, я вас понял, вы правы, но и ответ не противоречит вашим словам (поэтому уже я вас не понимаю). Если бы мы говорили точными формулировками, я бы сказал так же, как и вы. Поэтому давайте не тратить время на глупый спор, если ответ вам не нравится, то ставьте минус и разойдемся миром))

Comment: Я не знаю почему ты тратишь время на глупый спор. Тебе заделали замечание, поставили плюс, чтобы исправил ответ. Вместо этого ты начал спорить. Поскольку этот вопрос с тегом Java, то потрудись привести примеры Java кода.

Comment: @RomanC, я хотел узнать, допустил я ошибку или что-то в ответе не так. Я немного с вами побеседовал и узнал всё, что мне надо. Плюсы, минусы и теги мне не важны, я просто помогаю коллегам в свое удовольствие. Замечание считаю несущественным в контексте вопроса. А теперь просто вежливо намекаю, что беседа с моей стороны окончена, если вам больше нечего добавить. И кстати, вы всегда можете дать свой ответ.